# android app is not visible in the play store after I pushed it to Open Beta

Tags: android

I have pushed my app from alpha to Open Beta but I cannot see it on the playstore. I want to make the app visible on playstore but disable reviews and ratings. How can I get it to work ? The link here says that the app is visible to everyone https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213 ..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're referring to this:

> We're making open beta tests easier to find and participate in: **apps
>   that are available only as open betas and aren’t in production yet
>   will soon appear in Play search results**, users will be able to opt-in
>   from Play store listings directly, and users will be able to send you
>   private feedback through your Play store listing too.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2016/05/whats-new-in-google-play-at-io-2016.html)

This change was announced at Google I/O 2016. I assume they've updated their help docs, but this change has not gone live yet in the Play Store.

As far as i know, there is no official announcement on when will it go live, so all we can do is wait.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is publicly visible using a specific link:

```
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your.package.name
```

Edit: You won't be able to disable ratings and reviews unfortunately

Comment: I have seen few apps on playstore where comments are disabled. How are they doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

I put an app from closed beta into open beta a few weeks ago.
The app will not be visible in the store nor can you find it if you are not a tester already.

The thing that changes is that you no longer have to maintain an email list for your testers. You can provide them with a link to sign up by themselve.

Also reviews and comments are not posisble in open beta anyway.

Comment: I have seen few apps on playstore where comments are disabled. How are they doing it ?

Comment: I'm curious about how do you know that comments are disabled?

Comment: WHen I download the app on playstore it shows that comments for that app are disabled..

Comment: Can you link one of those apps? I have never heared about that before.